# Next.js Image keeps showing unconfigured error message

Tags: next.js, next-images

`` hostname "www.gravatar.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js ``

My config:

```
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["gravatar.com"],
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

I have restarted the serve after making the change to config. Completely at a loss at this point, only local images seem to work.

Comment: What's your next.js version?

Comment: version is 12.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two things:

- You've got `images` within `images` in your config
- You're missing `www.` in the `gravatar.com` domain (might not be the case, but just in case)

Comment: Copied it over wrong, updated original post. Still same issue. And I'm fairly certain you aren't supposed to include `www`

Comment: Weirdly enough adding www in *did* fix the issue despite the documentation here saying otherwise: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Answer (score 0):

need to do:

```
images: {
    domains: [YOUR_DOMAINS],
    disableStaticImages: true,
}
```

and in your config you placed images under images :

```
images: {
    images: {
      domains: ["gravatar.com"],
    },
    disableStaticImages: true,
  }
```

Comment: Looks like I copied over the block wrong, there is actually only one `images`. Updated main post to reflect. Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue and it seems adding [remotePatterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns) is the solution.

```
images: {
remotePatterns: [
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'res.cloudinary.com',
    port: '',
    pathname: '/my-bucket/**',
  },
],
```

},